# I would like to distinguish for clearing a cell vs changing a cell

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, cell

I need help to make a VBA to add the time stamp in the same row when a cell is changed.

This is what I made.

A value is entered in a cell, the next cell is activated by "enter".  I used offset to add the time stamp in the same row.

But the issue is when the cell content is deleted, the same cell is active, so the time stamp is updated in one row above, not the same row.

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rDependents As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rDependents = Target.Dependents
If Err.Number > 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(rDependents, Range("G9:G500")) Is Nothing Then
    Call Time_Stamp

End If
End Sub

Private Sub Time_Stamp()

ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=2).Activate
With Selection
.Value = Now
End With

ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=-3).Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to change the ActiveCell when using the Worksheet_Change event, because the ActiveCell could be anything, depending how the user enters the value.

- if they hit Enter and the system is configured to go to the next row down, then ActiveCell will be the next row down,
- it is possible to change that behaviour and Enter goes across instead of down
- the user could confirm the cell entry by clicking a random cell in the spreadsheet, i.e. ActiveCell could be anywhere.
- the user could click the green tick mark next to the formula bar and the cell selection does not change at all.

You cannot know what the active cell will be, so using `ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=-1` could end up anywhere.

Instead of the active cell, operate on the `target` object. You don't need to call another sub for that, you can do it right in the Change event

```
If Target = "" Then
    ' do nothing, or maybe you want to clear any previously existing time stamp like this
    'Cells(Target.Row, "E").clearContents
Else
    Cells(Target.Row, "E").Value = Now()
End If
```

Now you don't need to muck around with offset to get the row where the change happened, and the time stamp will only be set if the change resulted in a real value, not a blank cell.

If, for some reason you want to use a separate sub, just feed it the row number of Target as a parameter.